# unable to run  update query in database in android?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I am trying to update the starred field of contacts table or in other words I am trying to add a name to favourite list in my application.I have searched a lot but couldn't find anything specific to my case .update query is just not making any changes and not even throwing exception,not a thing in stack trace.

```
//appname used in the code is the name which I need to add to the starred list.. 
ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();          

Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,
            null, null, null, null);

ContentValues value=new ContentValues();
value.put("ContactsContract.Contacts.STARRED",1);

cur.moveToFirst();  
while(!cur.isLast()){

        String fetchname=cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));

        if((appname.equalsIgnoreCase(fetchname))==true)
        {    
            String starredvalue=cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.STARRED));
            try
                {                  
                cr.update(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,value,"starred=?",new String[]{starredvalue});
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();                    
            }
       }//if  
       cur.moveToNext();     
}//while
```

Answer (score 1):

From the [fine manual](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#update%28java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D%29):

> public int **update** (String table, ContentValues values, String whereClause, String[] whereArgs)
>
> *whereClause* the optional WHERE clause to apply when updating. Passing null will update all rows.

Your *whereClause* looks like this:

```
"starred='true'"
```

Notice that you don't have any placeholders (i.e. things like `col = ?`) in that SQL fragment? But you are supplying arguments for the non-existent placeholders in your *whereArgs* argument:

```
new String[]{starredvalue}
```

So the `update` call is looking for placeholder number one, not finding it in *whereClause*, and then so you get an "index out of range" exception.

I'm sure what you're trying to do but maybe you want your *whereClause* to be `"starred = ?"` (instead of `"starred='true'"`) or perhaps a `null` *whereArgs*.

Comment: cr.update(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,value,"starred='true'",null);I tried this ,the exception is gone but still a no show.by the way thanks for the reply.

Comment: @prof_jack: Have you tried `"starred=?"` with the *whereArgs*? Or perhaps you want `"starred=1"` and a `null` *whereArgs*, SQLite uses one and zero for booleans.

Comment: cr.update(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,value,ContactsContract.Contacts.STARRED+"=?",new String[]{starredvalue});yeah,I have tried this too,same as happened above,the exception is gone but the starred field is not getting updated.

Comment: I tried giving value 1 in place of true as in the edited code.I have been working on this thing from couple of days but couldn't find anything.kindly let me know if you come up with something.thanks..

Comment: @prof_jack: Can you look at the database directly and see what values the `starred` column really has? And maybe include the table schema in your question.

Comment: yeah,it is using 0 for not starred and 1 for the starred values.

Comment: And you do have values with a 1 when you use `"starred = 1"`, right?

Comment: no,it is still showing 0 in the database.that is the problem I guess.what I think that the exception is gone but the update has never been happened too.

Comment: Could it be that you have an open cursor, `cur`, when you call `update`?